# If statement check type of error

Tags: javascript

I get the following error:

```
{ [TokenExpiredError: jwt expired]
  name: 'TokenExpiredError',
  message: 'jwt expired',
  expiredAt: Wed Sep 30 2015 16:44:44 GMT+0200 (CEST) }
```

I've tried the following, without it working:

```
    try {
        // ...code
    } catch (err) {
        if (typeof err === 'TokenExpiredError') {
            // ...do stuff
        }

    }
```

I would like to check the object type. I know that I could check the message, but I would like to learn how to check the object type on the error object.

Comment: `typeof` returns only the very basic type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @biziclop I guess I must use instanceof then?

Comment: `typeof err` returns `'object'`. You want `instanceof` - or just check `err.name`.

Comment: @Bergi Post as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `err.name?`

Comment: @epascarello Was wanting to try against the object type. I must use instanceof according to Bergi.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the object type is the value of `err.name` and should be checked.

But if you want to use `instanceof`:

```
try {
    // ...code
} catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
        // ...do stuff
    }
}
```

That supposes `TokenExpiredError` is defined before (as a constructor function). Otherwise use `Error` for example.

NB: don't use quote because you pass a reference to the function.

Comment: I know how to do it that way, I was wanting to check against the actual object type. Not against the object property name.

Comment: @KarlMorrison That's not how types work. `typeof new URIError() === "object"`.

Comment: @Nit If you looked at the comments of the question you'll see that it was already pointed out :)